# Dragging item within droppable in material drawer reflects droppable in page (behind/underneath drawer)

Tags: reactjs, web, material-ui, drawer, react-beautiful-dnd

I have 2 droppables, one in page, and other one in MUI drawer.

#### Expected behavior

When re-arranging on drawer, it should not overlap droppable of page, rather re-arrange on drawer itself, even droppable behind it exists. Same should go for droppable of page.

#### Actual behavior

When I reorder item in drawer's droppable, it reflects in droppable of page where overlapped. and vice versa too.

#### Steps to reproduce

- Open drawer and try re-order items onto drawer (that will reflect in droppable of page)

#### Suggested solution?

After research I found this may occur because of `position: fixed` thing, and solution was to use React.Portal. I tried it, but not resolved the issue. Link below:
https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/stories/src/portal/portal-app.jsx

#### versions

React: 17.0.2
MUI: 4.12.4
RBD: 13.1.1

#### What browser are you using?

Chrome

#### Demo

I have created an example in code sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-https-yyg962

Assistance appreciated.